# How to handle the html as dom and delete the certain tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, titanium

I would like to handle the text as dom and delete whole this tag.

I am used to php ,so I have handled html as dom and deleted.

```
.
.
<div class="noneed">
I want to delete here
</div>
.
.
```

.js file

```
browXhr.open('GET', "http://google.com");                   
browXhr.onload = function() {
    try{
        html = this.responseText;
```

I would like to parse html and delete `<div class ="noneed">~</div>`
by titanium javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a phony element and use the responseText value in the new element innerHTML:

```
// ...
el = document.createElement('DIV')
el.innerHTML = this.responseText;

to_remove = el.querySelector('.noneed')
to_remove.parentNode.removeChild(to_remove)
```

Comment: Thanks,your idea is good aswell, but I am using htmlparser .https://gist.github.com/zeuxisoo/1016047